# Is there an easy way to add leading zeros to a string created via std::to_string(int)?

Tags: c++, string, formatting, std

I got the following `std::string` that I partially create through converting an `int` to a `string`:

```cpp
std::string text = std::string("FPS: " + std::to_string(1000 / d));
```

Example output:

> FPS: 60

Now, I would like to add leading zeros specifically to the `int` part, such that I get this output:

> FPS: 060

I already know how to achieve this for `stdout` with `std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5)` .

But I haven't found a solution for the simple `std::to_string()` conversion.

Comment: sprintf would work.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [stringstream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

It behaves exactly like std::cout but has a method str() to get the string you created.

For your problem it would probably look like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "FPS: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << std::to_string(1000 / d);
std::string text(ss.str());
```

Edit: To test the performance of this I created a dumb test program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        ss.clear();
        ss << "FPS: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << std::to_string(i);
        std::string text(ss.str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with `g++ -O3 main.cpp`. I then opened a terminal and started the program through `time`:

```
$ time ./a.out
./a.out  1,53s user 0,01s system 99% cpu 1,536 total
```

So 1.53s for 100k iterations (15.3µs per iteration on average) on my `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500 CPU @ 3.00GHz` CPU running a Linux 5.13.5 kernel the latest libstdc++

It's very long from an instruction perspective, tens of thousands of instructions is costly on small micro-processor, but on a modern system it's hardly ever a problem.

Comment: Ah alright. Works great, tho im not sure of the perfomance of stringstreams.
As maybe already indicated this is being called at a high frequency.

Comment: Actually the second line should be 
`ss << "FPS: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3)
       <<  std::to_string(1000 / d);`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `to_string` function here? Why not `ss << "FPS: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << (1000 / d);` ?

Comment: @JakobSachs I edited my answer to address both of your comments

Comment: @Tzig That performance test isn't really relevant. A clever compiler could optimize away the whole program, making it into `int main() {}`. You can use https://quick-bench.com/ to setup benchmarkings easily. I still don't see why you use `to_string` though.

Comment: If you have a performance constraint you should firstly mention that in the question, and secondly probably use a `std::string_view` over a pre-allocated `char` array. If you're already happy with concatenating temporary `std::string`s, your constraints aren't _that_ tight. Nevertheless, they should be explicit.

Comment: Small nitpick, since the stringstream is being used for output only, you should use `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::stringstream`

Answer (score 5):

You could count the length of the converted string and use that to create a string with zeroes:

```
size_t min_len = 3;
std::string text = std::to_string(1000 / d);
if(text.size() < min_len) text = std::string(min_len - text.size(), '0') + text;
text = "FPS: " + text;
```

A performance test comparing using this "strings only" approach to that of using `std::stringstream` *may* be interesting if you do this formatting a lot:

[quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/eQgs0seF4nci6MKm7vgoPtL0azk)
[image]

Comment: Also a good way, but less readable maybe. Question of personal taste i would say.
Thanks

Comment: @JakobSachs You're welcome. Yes, it's indeed a matter of personal taste. I often used `stringstream`s myself so I have nothing against them :-)

Answer (score 5):

In C++20, you might use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

```
std::format("{:03}", 1000 / d);
```

Comment: In which case, you can include the `FPS:` prefix in the format: `std::string text = std::format("FPS: {:03}", 1000 / d);`